# Maths — how to create moving waves with Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes, mathematics

I am this week learning wave equations, my very first time. I am learning those below. [image] 
[image]

Please give examples of how you'd use wave equations with Animation Nodes. Your way, please.

No ideas? How about waves on a long strip of plane below?
[image]

With wave movement on a same plane.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Theory

The [wave equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation) is a second order partial differential equation, which means solving it can done by [numerical integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration#Connection_with_differential_equations), perhaps using the simpler [Euler's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method). The one dimensional wave equation is as follows:

$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = c^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}
$$

Where $u$ is the displacement, $t$ is the time, and $x$ is the position. The partial derivative on the right hand side is the one dimensional *[Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator)*. So, to compute it, we use the *[Discrete Laplace Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Laplace_operator)*. In particular, we can use a one dimensional [convolution kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Laplace_operator#Implementation_via_operator_discretization), the kernel have the structure:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ -2 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Finally, to be able to solve this, we need to define the [initial conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_value_problem) of the system as well as its [boundary conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_value_problem). That is, we have to define the initial displacement and the initial velocity. Lets assume that at $t=0$ the velocity was zero ($\left.\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\right\rvert_{t=0} = 0$) and the displacement was zero everywhere except at a subset of the domain where it was a bell shaped curve. As for the boundary conditions, we shall use a [Periodic Boundary Condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_boundary_conditions).

## Implementation

First, give the displacement, we compute the discrete laplacian using the kernel outlined above, this is easily done by vectorization as follows:

[image: Discrete Laplacian]

Next, given the initial velocity, lets compute the velocity after $\delta$ time using Euler's method as follows:

[image: Compute Velocity]

Next, lets compute the displacement given an initial displacement and the velocity using Euler's method:

[image: Compute Displacement]

Next, we make a solver loop that takes the initial velocity and displacement and reassign them at each iteration:

[image: Solver]

Finally, we define the initial conditions as discussed before and display the simulation as a circular domain, we also enable per frame caching to get real time results:

[image: Initial Conditions]

By running the animation, we get:

[image: Result]

Which seems about right. It should be noted that this is not the most physically or mathematically accurate simulation and it is not computationally efficient either, this is just a simplified heuristic implementation to demonstrate the wave equation.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this. You are always a genius. I wish I can steal your brain and do great many things with it. Imagine all the years of learning gone inside that great brain of yours.

Comment: "Where *u* is the displacement, t is the time, and *x* is the position." I know *c* is for constant. Now, I have learned what *u* is. I was previously long stuck on *u.* Now, I know what it is and thank you for that. I am going to look up others like laplacian, discrete laplace operator, etc. Thanks for mentioning them.